# How can I return HTTP-400 from a BizTalk Rest service?

Tags: rest, biztalk, webhttpbinding, biztalk-2013r2

I am using BizTalk 2013 R2 and I have a RESTFUL service.

How can I return a HTTP-400 response to a client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `WCF.OutboundHttpStatusCode` property in message assignment shape:

```
MyResponseMessage(WCF.OutboundHttpStatusCode) = "400";
```

Answer (score 2):

Oleg's answer will work if you have an Orchestration

If you want a messaging only solution you will have to have a Pipeline Component set the same context property.

For this we tend to use the [BizTalk Business Rules Engine Pipeline Framework](https://github.com/mbrimble/brepipelineframework)

In your Business Rule policy, use the SetCustomContextProperty from the BREPipelineFramework.SampleInstructions.ContextInstructions in your Actions and set the context name of *OutboundHttpStatusCode* and a namespace of `http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2006/01/Adapters/WCF-properties` and set the value to 400

The picture below show what it looks like, but with a 404

[image]

Disclosure: This framework was written by someone I have worked with.